# How to redirect from a mysql query in node.js webapp?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making a simple node.js webapp for inserting data into a database with a condition - when there's two instances with the same time attribute, the insert query isn't called and you get redirected to a simple html page with a message that you have to pick another time.

My question is, how can I redirect from a block of code belonging to query? or is there another way to let user know that he has to pick another time?

```js
app.post('/', function(req, resp) {
    try {
        var name = req.body.name;
        var date = req.body.date + " " + req.body.time;
        var phone = req.body.phone;
        var spz = req.body.spz;
        var typeOfProblem = req.body.typeOfProblem;

        con.query(("SELECT COUNT(*) AS datecheck FROM `objednani` WHERE datetime = '"+ date +"'"), function(err, result){
            if (err) throw err;
            if(result[0].datecheck > 1){
                console.log("preplneno"); // THIS IS THE POINT WHERE I WANT TO REDIRECT THE USER
            } else {
                con.query(("INSERT INTO objednani (name, datetime, phone, spz, typeofproblem) " + "VALUES ('"+name+"','"+date+"','"+phone+"','"+spz+"','"+typeOfProblem+"')"), function (err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log("uspech");
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        resp.redirect('/fail');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `resp.redirect('/fail');` inside your query block, or anywhere in `function(req, resp)` function. You don't need to throw and catch.

As another suggestion: you can try parameter embedding for your sqls. otherwise you can be subject to sql injection attacks.

Comment: hey, i already tried that before, but it throwed some errors earlier that resp is undefined. I tried that again to be absolutely sure, and now it works, so i guess i made some syntax mistkae or something :D as for your suggestion, this is only a school project, so i don't really worry about me being subject to attacks, but thanks for pointing this out :)

Comment: good to know. reminder: dont forget to upvote useful posts :)

Comment: Well, i tried to, but "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." I have too low reputation :( :D

Comment: Now you have more than 15 :)